# How to set selected index to 0 of a combo box from another class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox, selectedindex

I try to test if I can change the combo box selected index when I press a button, but it doesn't work for me what ever I try if my combo box was added to my frame from another class, may you please tell me what I miss ?

My class where I created the combo box is:

```
package MyPackage;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class AddMyBox {

    private JComboBox combobox;
    String[] array = {"Select", "1", "2", "3"};

    public JComboBox theBox() {
        combobox = new JComboBox();
        combobox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(array));
        combobox.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 20);
        return combobox;
    }

}
```

and the class where my frame is created and where I add the component is:

```
package MyPackage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

        // adding the comboBox from class AddMyBox
        AddMyBox getBox = new AddMyBox();
        getContentPane().add(getBox.theBox());

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    // if selected index is 1 make it 0 when the button is pressed
                    if(getBox.theBox().getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
                        getBox.theBox().setSelectedIndex(0);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 63, 414, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        setSize(500,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void MyFrame1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

And my main class is :
    package MyPackage;

```
public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyFrame getFrame = new MyFrame();
        getFrame.MyFrame1();
    }

}
```

Comment: *"may you please tell me what I miss ?"* Basic OOP, which should be figured out in two classes meant to be run from the command line. GUIs are an advanced topic, and you should already understand object references and encapsulation of attributes by method access.

Answer (score 5):

```
public JComboBox theBox() {
    combobox = new JComboBox();
    combobox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(array));
    combobox.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 20);
    return combobox;
}
```

Every time you invoke the `theBox()` method a new combo box is created, so the logic in your ActionListener is referencing a combo box that is not visible on the frame, so your visible combo box will never change.

The structure of your class is wrong. You need to:

1. create a constructor for the class which simply creates the combo box. That is basically you need to move the first 3 statements to the constructor.
2. change the `theBox()` method to simply return the `comboBox` variable. (this is the only statement left after you remove the first 3 statements.

Edit:

I copied the other issues from Hovercrafts answer since the OP won't be able to reference them:

Other issues:

- This `combobox.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 20);` is not something you will want to do -- including using magic numbers, making this method extremely inflexible, and suggesting that you're using a `null` layout, something you really want to avoid.
- `getContentPane().setLayout(null);` yeah. Don't do this. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- `catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception }` -- do what the comment suggests -- **handle** your exceptions and never ignore them. Else you'll be doing the programming equivalent of driving your car with your eyes closed.

Comment: No, you're right. It's my brain that's not yet functioning -- more coffee is needed! 1+

Comment: @camickr
Wooooow, it seems so complicated topic, actually what Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested did help me and made it works.
I will try to read again and again your comment to really understand it, thank you so much

Comment: @AboelmagdSaad, its not that complicated. It is basic design of any class The constructor should be used to create the objects of the class. A "getter" method should just return the reference to the object, not create a new one. So really your `theBox()` method should be called `getBox()`. Look at the API for any class in the JDK and you will see "getter" and "setter" methods for the class.